# Showing continuity at $x=0$ in a normed space implies a linear operator $A$ is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A:X\to Y$ be a linear operator between normed spaces. I want to show that continuity of $A$ at $0$ implies $A$ is bounded.

Let $A$ be continuous at $0$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $\delta > 0$ such that if $||x - 0|| = ||x|| < \delta$,
$$
||Ax - A0|| = ||Ax|| < \varepsilon.
$$
Let $x\in X$. Define $\alpha>0$ such that $\alpha||x|| < \delta$, which is the same as $||\alpha x|| < \delta$. 
Therefore,
$$
||A\alpha x|| < \varepsilon,
$$
that is,
$$
||A x|| < \frac{\varepsilon}{\alpha}.
$$
Define $\gamma$ such that $\varepsilon = \gamma||x||$. Then we have
$$
||A x|| < \frac{\gamma ||x||}{\alpha},
$$
and hence $A$ is bounded. Is this a valid proof?

Comment: I think it's not valid because $\alpha$ depends on the choice of $x$. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator#Equivalence_of_boundedness_and_continuity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $x$ is arbitrary at first, but later when you define $\gamma$, you make it an element of the subset $\{x : ||x||=\frac \epsilon\gamma\}$ of $X$. So $||Ax|| \lt \frac {\gamma ||x||}{\alpha}$ is not true for all $x \in X$. In short $\gamma$ depends on $||x||$ as per your definition. Thus as $||x||$ varies, $\gamma$ also varies. Similarly $\alpha$ depends on $x$. But we want a fixed $K \gt 0$ such that $||Ax|| \le K||x||$ for all $x \in X$ to show that $A$ is bounded.